# const parameter

Tags: c++, constants

In C++, does the following make sense?

```
main()
{
 int a=10;
 fun(a);
}

void fun(const int a)
{
...
}
```

I can see a program similar to this compile but have linker issues. I just wanted to confirm if assigning a non const var to a const var is apt in C++.

Comment: it is allowed, whenever it makes sense is another issue.

Comment: Could the linker issues be because `fun()` is defined after `main()`? Try adding a prototype above `main()`.

Comment: It's not assignment, it *binds* the `const` parameter with name `a` to the value `10`. If you think that makes no difference, try it with a parameter whose type has both copy ctor and `operator=` defined.

Comment: Why do i always see function names `fun` mostly in examples 0_o

Comment: M3taSpl0it: well, I think it's just fun!

Comment: @user844631: You should post the errors that you are getting. They might be related or not to the question you are asking, and without the errors is hard to *guess* what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is OK.

`a` cannot be reassigned in `fun()`, exactly as if it would have been declared that way:

```
void fun(int param)
{
    const int a(param);

    ...

    a = 5; // this is illegal and won't compile.
}
```

As it is passed by copy, there is no impact on `main()`'s `a` anyway. Even if `fun()`'s `a` was declared as non-const and modified.

Answer (score 3):

It would make sens if you added return types to your functions and had forward-declared `fun` before you called it (or reversed the order of your functions in that compilation unit).

For a plain `int`, it doesn't change anything for the caller - the called function can't change the value of that variable in the caller regardless of that qualifier. But for the called function, the parameter is `const`, so it can't be modified - that makes a difference, not sure if that generally "usefull" or not.

Now consider this:

```
int foo(int& a);
int bar(int const& a);
```

Those are two different beasts. `bar` can only read `a`, and can take either a plain `int` or a `const int` (or a `const int&`).

`foo`, on the other hand, can change `a` if it sees fit, and cannot take a `const`.

See the [Const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) entry in the C++FAQ Lite for more on this, including information about how this applies (or not) to const-pointers, pointers-to-const and const-pointer-to-const.

Comment: It does matter in the definition, as the compiler will complain if you try to modify the argument in the function definition. In the function declaration, that `const` is stripped.

Comment: Nitpicking a bit, (well, I am not sure that this is nitpicking really), the exact same behavior applies to pointers, note *pointers*, not the pointed memory. The equivalent with a pointer to int would be `void fun( int * const )`, and the `const` there is again stripped in the declaration, maintained in the definition; which is different from `void fun( int const * )` (equivalently `void fun( const int* )`) where the *type* changes from pointer to int, to pointer to const int. That is where the difference lays: top-level const will be removed any other one will be kept.

Comment: @David: ok. I chickened out and referred to the C++FAQ for the pointer part :-/

Answer (score 3):

In a function declaration the top level<sup>1</sup> `const` is stripped out by the compiler, while it is kept in the definition.

The reason is that the top level element is *copied*, and from the point of view of the caller it does not really matter whether the copy is constant or not, so on that end const-ness is not an issue. On the other end, in the definition of the function the argument cont-ness is maintained as it can help the compiler detect unintended modifications of the argument inside the function.

So basically:

```
void foo( int );
void foo( const int );    // redeclaration of the same function
void foo( const int x ) {
   ++x;                   // error: x is const!!
}
```

In the code above there are two exactly equivalent declarations of `foo` (the compiler will remove the `const` from the declaration), and a single definition. Because the in the signature of `foo` in the definition `x` is declared as a constant integer, the compiler will complain if you try to increment it.

Some people will use the `const` in the definition to get the compiler to flag `++x` as erroneous, but it is not common. On the other hand, whether the argument is declared as `int` or `const int`, for the caller they are the same.

<sup>1</sup> Note that this only applies to the top level const, which is applicable to arguments passed by value and pointers, but never to references (a reference is always const: you cannot reassign the reference). So these are different function declarations:

```
void f( int& );
void f( int const & );
void f( int* );            // equivalent to void f( int * const )
void f( int const * );     // equivalent to void f( int const * const )
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make much sense because what you get in the function is a copy of the variable, not the variable itself. But this is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a non-const to a const

Comment: `const int a = 9; int b = a;` is valid.  you are thinking of references

Comment: I think you mean you can't bind a const to a non-const reference.  You may be able to assign consts to non-consts.  You can assign const strings to non-const strings, and vice versa, because, the assignment operator makes a copy.  (`const string cs; string s=cs;` is allowed, but `const string cs; string & s=cs;` is not.)

Answer (score 0):

The "assignment" is ok - a in fun is a new variable which is kept constant inside fun.

But fun should have a return type, i.e. void.
And there should be a declaration of fun before using it in main.